# Creating <select> with onchange and eventListener

Tags: javascript

How would I take this:

```
<select onchange='disable(this)'> //options here  </select>
```

and make it into a createElement and eventListener? I don't know how to add the onchange="disable(this)".

So far I have:

```
var optionList = ["default", "yes", "no"];

var td = document.createElement("td");
selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.addEventListener("change", lockSelect, false);
td.appendChild(selectList);
newTableRow.appendChild(td);

for (var j = 0; j < optionList.length; j++)
{
   option = document.createElement("option");
   option.value = optionList[j];
   option.text = optionList[j];
   selectList.appendChild(option);
 }
```

This makes the `<select>` and `<options>`, but I cant figure out how to make the `onchange=disable(this)`

Comment: `disable()` is a function. Can you please show it and what it does?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nothing yet. I'm just trying to figure out how to call it...

Comment: TIPS&TRICKS: Don't append elements (`option` elements in your case) one-by-one - **after** the parent is inserted into the DOM, **but before!** - when the `select` element is created and still in memory. Than, once you append children to it - send your `select` into the DOM.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan should I change this `td.appendChild(selectList);
newTableRow.appendChild(td);` to outside the options for loop?

Comment: Yes, but **not** *outside* but **after** the `for` loop.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so like this? https://jsbin.com/hocofutihe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes. exactly. Such coding style is 1: easier to read 2: makes fast &  performant programs 3: leverages document repaints and relayouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function for `lockSelect`. You have not show the function for `disable` so I have to guess.

`lockSelect` should call `disable` passing the event target element to it.

It might be better to just change the disabled function to operate on an event object instead. and pass that directly to the event listener.

```
function disable(e) {
  e.target.disabled = true
}
```

```js
var optionList = ["default", "yes", "no"];
var newTableRow = document.querySelector('tr')

function disable(element) {
  element.disabled = true
}

function lockSelect(e) {
  disable(e.target)
}

var td = document.createElement("td");
selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.addEventListener("change", lockSelect, false);
td.appendChild(selectList);
newTableRow.appendChild(td);

for (var j = 0; j < optionList.length; j++) {
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = optionList[j];
  option.text = optionList[j];
  selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Idk what I was thinking but I guess I could've just done  it all inside the lockSelect function...

Comment: @qwiqwiqwiqwiqwi - Yes, you can just have `function lockSelect() { this.disabled = true; }`, because an event handler bound with `addEventListener()` will have `this` set to the element in question.